# Finding sunspots on fits image via OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, fits

I am currently working with astronomical data(Images), and my task is to write a program which finds sunspots on given image in fits format.

As I understood, the task is OpenCV related, but I have encountered a huge obstacle with formats. The Image data is 2D float32 numpy array which when given to OpenCV loses all details.

I have tried converting float32 into uint8 as well, however the result was not good.

[image]  [image]

left: before(matplotlib), right: after(cv2)

As it is seen, details were lost and it is not a good picture to be finding spots on. So, maybe there is alternative way of solving this?

```
[import cv2

from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img_l = fits.open('hmi.Ic_45s.20170605_000000_TAI.2.continuum.fits')
img = img_l\[0\].data

plt.imshow(img) #Showing Image in matplotlib
cv2.imshow('',img) #The image is white round with black background

image = np.array(img/255, dtype = np.uint8) #Converting float32 to uint8
cv2.imshow('', image) #Getting converted image
```

Comment: `#Converting float32 to uint8` - this is where the details go. As far I know cv2 can work with floating point images so don't convert to uint8. Just make sure the image is within range 0..1.

Comment: Yes, this really did help. Thank you!

Comment: Matplotlib comes with a number of built-in normalization functions: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html  Linear scaling might not be what you want though, but you can use log scaling, power law scaling, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with another model, where do I get fits files of sunspots