# Aligning images of the sun - but they're drifting

Tags: python, image-processing, astronomy

I've been aligning over 200 images of the sun taken in sequence in order to analyse them at a later point.

I thought I had managed, but when playing back a video of all the images in sequence I noticed that the sun drifts downwards. I believe this is because in some images the full disc is not present, and hence my aligning them "by the centroid" is wrong in some way.

Here are some examples of what I mean by drift:
[image: My first image where the sun is in the correct position]
[image: My final image where the sun has drifted as I tried to align the images]

I believe this drift is due to how I find my centroid for each disk - as the full disk is not present in every FITS image, the centroid slowly moves to a different position and the alignment skews.

My code for this is here:

```
def get_centroid(data): 
    #data is extracted from a FITS file
    
    #getting data centroid
    y_index, x_index = np.where(data >= 1e4) 
    #threshold is set to only include bright circle (sun) and not background

    #calculate the centroid
    centroid_y = np.mean(y_index)
    centroid_x = np.mean(x_index)
    
    return(centroid_y, centroid_x)
```

I've realised this only works if the full circle is present - in some of my images, parts of the sun disk are cut off.

I'm struggling to edit my function so that if one of the x or y axes is shorter (i.e. if part of the circle is cut off) I could adjust the indices to make it as if the full circle was there - so that my centroid is truly the centre of the circle and I could continue alignment that way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you let us know what the data looks like in data? Is it an contour or points from inside the circle?

Comment: the only idea i have right now is to fit a circle to your data and calculate the center of the fitted circle. This should compensate the missing data.

Comment: There are many simple approaches you could take to align these images. For example extract the outlines and use RANSAC to line them up. But fitting a circle to each image individually as suggested by Marco is also a very good idea.

Comment: @MarcoF. The data is from a FITS image, so it's numpy arrays with the coordinates and intensity - so I believe that would mean points from inside the circle. The threshold value of 1e4 I have in the function selects the points on the disk of the sun (as lower than this in intensity is the black background)

Comment: if it is always cut off at the same side you may be able to calculate the center point with the help of the boundaries (ymin/ymax and xmin/xmax). You calculate the width and with that you can calculate the center point in height.

Comment: Extend your images if necessary. Then use HoughCircles() or fitEllipse to the sun circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you. I used the ideia presentend [OpenCV: Fitting a single circle to an image (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621959/opencv-fitting-a-single-circle-to-an-image-in-python). Also sorry for the huge answer.

First lets create a larger canvas so we can centralize the sun image later.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img1 = cv.imread('6cTxW.png')
img2 = cv.imread('CVxDC.png')

def image_inside_larger_canvas(img,size):
    # Define the size of the larger canvas
    larger_canvas_size = size  # Change the dimensions as needed

    # Create a larger canvas of the specified size
    larger_canvas = np.zeros((larger_canvas_size[1], larger_canvas_size[0], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Calculate the position to place the image in the center of the larger canvas
    x_offset = (larger_canvas_size[0] - img.shape[1]) // 2
    y_offset = (larger_canvas_size[1] - img.shape[0]) // 2

    # Paste the image onto the larger canvas
    larger_canvas[y_offset:y_offset + img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset + img.shape[1]] = img

    return larger_canvas
```

Now is the image processing part, the explanation is inside the code.

```py
#create a larger canvas
img1_larger = image_inside_larger_canvas(img2,(1200,1200))

#convert to gray
img1_gray = cv.cvtColor(img1_larger, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#binarization so we can fit the countours
th_val,binarized1 = cv.threshold(img1_gray,1,255,cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# this part will get you the outer shape of the sun, in
# other words, the perimeter (also called morph gradient)
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
binarized1_eroded = cv.erode(binarized1,kernel)
gradient = binarized1 - binarized1_eroded

#finding countours and finding the biggest area
contours,_ = cv.findContours(gradient,cv.RETR_TREE,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
sorted_areas = np.sort(areas)

#choosing the one with the biggest area
cnt = contours[areas.index(sorted_areas[-1])]

# fit circle
(x,y),radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
center = (int(x),int(y))
radius = int(radius)

# fit ellipse (blue)
ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(cnt)

(ellipse_center, axes, angle) = ellipse

# Get ellipse center for later use
x_c,y_c = int(ellipse_center[0]), int(ellipse_center[1])

#change to RGB so we can plot the fitted ellipses and circles
img1_gray = cv.cvtColor(img1_gray, cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

# draw ellipse and circle to see the process
# you can remove this later.
cv.ellipse(img1_gray,ellipse,(255,0,0),2)
cv.circle(img1_gray,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)

# Draw a dot also
_ = cv.circle(img1_gray, (x_c,y_c), 10, (255, 0, 0), -1)
```

Now you just need to translate the sun to the center of the canvas. Wich is done by using `warpAffine` with the T matrix that uses the distance of the ellipse center from the middle of the canvas.

```py
height, width = img1_gray.shape[:2] 

#get the middle of the canvas
middle_h, middle_w = height // 2, width // 2

# the matrix tarfomation
T = np.float32([[1, 0, middle_w-x_c], [0, 1, middle_h-y_c]]) 

# use warpAffine to transform the image using the matrix, T 
img_translation = cv.warpAffine(img1_gray, T, (width, height)) 

# Draw a horizontal line on the canvas to check if it is in the middle.
line = img_translation.shape[1] // 2
cv.line(img_translation, (0, line), (img_translation.shape[0], line), (0, 255, 0), 2) 
cv.line(img_translation, (line, 0), (line, img_translation.shape[0]), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Draw a dot on the canvas
cv.circle(img_translation, (np.abs(x_c), np.abs(y_c)), 10, (0, 255, 0), -1)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.imshow(img_translation)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('dale1.png')
plt.show()
```

The green dot is the old sun center, the red circle is the ellipse, the green circle is the circle and, the green lines are the image center lines.

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would using OpenCV work with FITS files is my only question - I've had some issues working with them as images. Otherwise thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: Hey @SevHryn with a quick google search i found: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913007/finding-sunspots-on-fits-image-via-opencv), [link2 if you can use c++](https://answers.opencv.org/question/1901/reading-fits-flexible-image-transport-system-images/). OpenCV can work with float32 images, it just have to be in the 0-1 range. But if you encounter some problem, convert the image into uint8 and with that you can use OpenCV to create for example a binary mask, then apply the binary mask in your FITS image.